# Position of icons on the desktop of windows using hexadecimal code

Tags: windows-7, icons

After using `icosauve` to save the position of icon on the desktop windows, I want to reposition an icon of one the elements. Using `Icosauve` I get a hexadecimal code of the icon, my problem is that I can't udnerstand the position, which is in hexadecimal. This is the code of an icon naming Computer:

```
"Computer"=hex:1a,00,00,00,02,00,00,00
```

I don't know how to interpret this so that I can reposition the icon.

Comment: My wild speculation is that it is a little endian representation of the pixel for one of the corners.  So if you flip it you get (0x1a,0x2), or (20,2).  Not sure about the order of the axis.  In any case, why just just try playing around with various values.  It doesn't seem like you should be able to hurt anything.

Answer (score 2):

Put 4 icons in the corners (1 in each).
Get their hexes.
You will now have a fully relevant coordinate system, you will exactly see how X and Y vary by position.

Note that the values are also resolution-dependent (the XY furthest from 0,0).